# How to group rows by ID and calculate mean and IQR

Tags: r, mean, data-cleaning, reshape2, iqr

I have a long format dataframe,`my data`, where there are 101 participants who each receive a score on 51 trials (`Event`), like so:

`dput(head(mydata, 200))`

```
`structure(list(Participant = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4), Score = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 45, 75, 20, -4, 
6, 12, 10, 5, 0, 25, 2, 48, 17, 7, 2, 30, 32, 40, 0, 10, 32, 
0, 13, -1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 10, 3, 16, 9, 0, 26, 33, 
9, 5, 2, 0, 0, 5, 50, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 10, 10, 15, 0, 10, 5, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 79, 5, 35, 0, 0, 5, 0, 10, 10, 30, 30, 10, 25, 
5, 25, 0, 75, 0, 70, 0, 0, 1, 5, 10, 0, 15, 0, 0, 55, 5, 40, 
0, 1, 30, 5, 15, 30, 9, 5, 1, 20, 11, 8, 10, 30, 6, 15, 3, 15, 
0, 20, 25, 16, 3, 38, 5, 15, 19, 0, 20, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 17, 25, 
40, 0, 31, 53, 2, 30, 0, 10, 3, 13, 0, 5, 22, 5, 4, 20, 0), Event = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 
44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 
46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L
)), row.names = c(1L, 105L, 209L, 313L, 417L, 521L, 625L, 729L, 
833L, 937L, 1041L, 1145L, 1249L, 1353L, 1457L, 1561L, 1665L, 
1769L, 1873L, 1977L, 2081L, 2185L, 2289L, 2393L, 2497L, 2601L, 
2705L, 2809L, 2913L, 3017L, 3121L, 3225L, 3329L, 3433L, 3537L, 
3641L, 3745L, 3849L, 3953L, 4057L, 4161L, 4265L, 4369L, 4473L, 
4577L, 4681L, 4785L, 4889L, 4993L, 5097L, 5201L, 2L, 106L, 210L, 
314L, 418L, 522L, 626L, 730L, 834L, 938L, 1042L, 1146L, 1250L, 
1354L, 1458L, 1562L, 1666L, 1770L, 1874L, 1978L, 2082L, 2186L, 
2290L, 2394L, 2498L, 2602L, 2706L, 2810L, 2914L, 3018L, 3122L, 
3226L, 3330L, 3434L, 3538L, 3642L, 3746L, 3850L, 3954L, 4058L, 
4162L, 4266L, 4370L, 4474L, 4578L, 4682L, 4786L, 4890L, 4994L, 
5098L, 5202L, 3L, 107L, 211L, 315L, 419L, 523L, 627L, 731L, 835L, 
939L, 1043L, 1147L, 1251L, 1355L, 1459L, 1563L, 1667L, 1771L, 
1875L, 1979L, 2083L, 2187L, 2291L, 2395L, 2499L, 2603L, 2707L, 
2811L, 2915L, 3019L, 3123L, 3227L, 3331L, 3435L, 3539L, 3643L, 
3747L, 3851L, 3955L, 4059L, 4163L, 4267L, 4371L, 4475L, 4579L, 
4683L, 4787L, 4891L, 4995L, 5099L, 5203L, 4L, 108L, 212L, 316L, 
420L, 524L, 628L, 732L, 836L, 940L, 1044L, 1148L, 1252L, 1356L, 
1460L, 1564L, 1668L, 1772L, 1876L, 1980L, 2084L, 2188L, 2292L, 
2396L, 2500L, 2604L, 2708L, 2812L, 2916L, 3020L, 3124L, 3228L, 
3332L, 3436L, 3540L, 3644L, 3748L, 3852L, 3956L, 4060L, 4164L, 
4268L, 4372L, 4476L, 4580L, 4684L, 4788L), class = "data.frame")`
```

I want to calculate the mean and interquartile range for `Score` by each `Participant` across the 51 trials, labelled here as `Event`. I then want to remove the observations in which a participant's `Score` if more the ±3 outside of the interquartile range.

What's the most efficient way of doing this?

I have looked into the `cast` function in `reshape2` in hopes of transposing the dataframe into a wide format first, but I've been unsuccessful.

I've also looked into grouping the rows by `Participant` but have not found a clear enough tutorial to guide me through this.

Comment: Do you want to group by `Event` or just by `Participant`?

Comment: Just by `Participant`. So I'd like the mean and IQR for each participants' `Score`s across the 51 trials (`Event`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what the question asks for, grouping `Score` by `Participant`.

```
agg <- aggregate(Score ~ Participant, mydata, function(x){
  qq <- quantile(x, probs = c(1, 3)/4)
  iqr <- diff(qq)
  lo <- qq[1] - 1.5*iqr
  hi <- qq[2] + 1.5*iqr
   c(Mean = mean(x), IQR = unname(iqr), lower = lo, high = hi)
 }) 

agg <- cbind(agg[1], agg[[2]])
agg
#  Participant       Mean  IQR lower.25% high.75%
#1           1  0.3529412  0.0      0.00     0.00
#2           2 12.4117647 18.5    -27.75    46.25
#3           3 13.6666667 17.5    -26.25    43.75
#4           4 12.4255319 17.0    -22.50    45.50
```

Note that the `IQR` for `Participant == 1` is zero because all values are `0` except for a `Score == 18`. That's an outlier, not between `Q1` and `Q3`.

```
mrg <- merge(mydata, agg[c(1, 4, 5)])
inx <- apply(mrg[c(2, 4, 5)], 1, function(x) x[1] < x[2] | x[1] > x[3])
result <- mydata[!inx, ]
row.names(result) <- NULL

head(result)
#  Participant Score Event
#1           1     0     1
#2           1     0     2
#3           1     0     3
#4           1     0     4
#5           1     0     5
#6           1     0     6
```

Final clean up.

```
rm(inx, mrg)
```